# Why rust is failing to build command for openssl-sys v0.9.60 even after local installation?

Tags: rust, openssl

I'm facing the error `failed to run custom build command for openssl-sys v0.9.60` while trying to build my rust program. Here are the `main.rs` and the `Cargo.toml` files.

main.rs

```rust
extern crate reqwest;

fn main() {
    let mut resp = reqwest::get("http://www.governo.mg.gov.br/Institucional/Equipe").unwrap();
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "get_sct"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["myname <myemail>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.10.10"
```

I installed **openssl** locally (as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182594/error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-openssl-v0-9-24)), using:

```sh
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
cd openssl
./config --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Finally, I ran `export OPENSSL_DIR="/usr/local/ssl"`

I noted I already had a anaconda instalation of **openssl** which was in my default path. To change the default path of **openssl** to the github instalation I ran `chmod -x MYPATH/anaconda3/bin/openssl` and now `which openssl` returns `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.

I also have **pkg-config** installed (as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364214/why-doesnt-the-rust-crate-openssl-sys-compile)). Running `which pkg-config` returns `/usr/bin/pkg-config`

However, when I run `cargo run` again the program print the same error message. Here is the entire error message:

```
> cargo run
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.60
   Compiling tokio v0.2.24
   Compiling pin-project-internal v0.4.27
   Compiling pin-project-internal v1.0.2
   Compiling mime_guess v2.0.3
   Compiling url v2.2.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.60`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/PACKAGEPATH/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-db18d493257de4f7/build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_LIB_DIR
  OPENSSL_LIB_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR
  X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_DIR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_DIR
  OPENSSL_DIR = /usr/local/ssl

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'OpenSSL library directory does not exist: /usr/local/ssl/lib', /home/lucas/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.60/build/main.rs:66:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build faile
```

It looks like that rust is searching for ssl in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`. In fact, there is a `/usr/local/ssl` folder in my PC, but there is no `lib` there.

What am I doing wrong here? How can make my local installation of openssl work with rust correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635680/14009899 sudo apt install libssl-dev
worked for me

Comment: I wrote up an issue for this here https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1865 - my workaround was to use the "feature=vendored" mentioned in comments to answers below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have no experience with installing this myself but may be able to give some pointers.

First of all about your effort to install OpenSSL. After cloning the repository, you do not select any particular branch before configuring and making. This means that you are building the `master` branch, which is an evolving version of OpenSSL 3.0.0. This is not a supported version according to [the crate's documentation](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.32/openssl/). In order to build a supported version of OpenSSL, you will have to switch to some 1.1.1 branch or tag. Alternatively, you can download the 1.1.1 version from [OpenSSL's download page](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

That said, it does not seem necessary to install OpenSSL from source. Under the section [Automatic](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.32/openssl/#automatic), the documentation explains that the crate can deal with all kinds of typical OpenSSL installations. It may be easier for you to follow that, if possible in your case. If so, then you should unset the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable otherwise that will (continue to) override the crate's automatic mechanisms to find the OpenSSL installation.

If you still want to stick with the [Manual](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.32/openssl/#manual) configuration, then indeed you should use environment variables, and `OPENSSL_DIR` seems a convenient one. However, it does not mean the same thing as the `openssldir` parameter that you used in your configure command `./config --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl`. To get the details, check out [the meaning of that configuration parameter](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md#openssldir). In fact, the crate's meaning of `OPENSSL_DIR` corresponds to [the `--prefix` setting](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md#prefix) (which you did not configure).

The problem you are running into now is that your `OPENSSL_DIR` variable points to your directory for OpenSSL configuration files, whereas the crate expects it to point to the top of the actual OpenSSL installation directory tree (which in your case seems to reside at `/usr/local`).

Comment: I didn't realize at the time the full implication of what you said. But for automatic installation it is sufficient add `openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }` to Cargo.toml.

Comment: This might not be sufficient. In my case, I already had `libssl-dev` installed, but, for reasons unknown, in a different laptop (with a *fresh* Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install) it'd still run into a similar issue. Here, the `reqwest` crate was the culprit and you have to set `default-features = false` and add `rustls-tls-native-roots` to the `features` list in the Cargo.toml file to get it to use a pure Rust TLS implementation and avoid other system library-specific issues.

Comment: @Lucas was a lifesaver. The most useful answer here was a comment. I was hitting this issue with rust-bert's convert-tensor script, that executes a cargo-built binary. Needed to slip that into the Cargo.toml so it'd load an openssl version that wouldn't fail.

Comment: @Lucas your comment worked for me, it might be good to turn this into a proper answer so I can upvote it.
Finally got a green build: https://github.com/timabell/gitopolis/actions/runs/4552699507/jobs/8028367202
Thank you!

Comment: ... the reason "features = vendored" works is because it toggles a "feature" of the openssl crate that causes it to build openssl from the C source instead of looking for the shared library (which for some reason isn't being found) - https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/#vendored

Answer (score 60):

This solved the issue for me in Ubuntu:

```sh
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Comment: for fedora/cantos it's ```yum install openssl openssl-devel -y ```

Comment: This is the most specific correct answer for debian and derivative distros.  Crate `openssl-sys` should document their dependency on the *developer* bindings for openssl. See https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1759.

Comment: can confirm it works on debian 12 (bullseye) as of jul 2023.

Comment: We also needed to run `sudo apt install pkg-config` on Ubuntu Jammy (22.04).

Answer (score 21):

I used the following set of commands

```
 sudo apt install pkg-config
 sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Answer (score 12):

On fedora 36 I was getting `error: failed to run custom build command for openssl-sys v0.9.77` when trying to install `cargo-generate` using `cargo install cargo-generate`

`openssl-devel` and `pkg-config` were already installed.

There was another complain below the main one:

> Can't locate FindBin.pm in @INC (you may need to install the FindBin
> module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.34
> /usr/local/share/perl5/5.34 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at
> ./Configure line 15.

The solution was:

```
sudo dnf install perl
```

Surprisingly, `perl` was already installed but by running `sudo dnf install perl` "some additional perl stuff" got installed which resolved the issue!

Comment: this worked for me. really weird but I'll take it. @Mamad any ideas on why this was the case?

Comment: @ArjunPatel I'm not entirely sure, `perl` was already installed but by running `sudo dnf install perl` "some additional perl stuff" got installed which ultimately resolved the issue!

Answer (score 7):

I ran rust on Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu). The following commands have worked for me.

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev

sudo apt install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 4):

run :

```sh
sudo apt install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following commands on Ubuntu on Windows:

```
 sudo apt install libudev-dev
 sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.04 I had a different issue associated with this error:

> run pkg_config fail: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"openssl\"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
>
> error: could
> not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys'
> crate
>
> --- stderr
>
> Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config
> search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing
> `openssl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>
> No package
> 'openssl' found"

I had already installed `libssl-devel` and `pkg-config`.

I solved this by searching for `openssl.pc`, which was located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/openssl.pc`.

I could solve it by setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` manually.

Answer (score 2):

To all the orphans left behind by Unclesoft stuck with Windows:

```
cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.95
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.95`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `D:\dev\samples\rust\kafka_demo\target\debug\build\openssl-sys-c2690b7cfe32b0fd\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
... OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_DIR
X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_DIR unset
```

To fix, steps below, but they take a long time (~1hr):
[How to work with OpenSSL for Rust within a Windows development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912871/how-to-work-with-openssl-for-rust-within-a-windows-development-environment)

```
clone vcpkg https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
open directory where you've cloned vcpkg
run ./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
run ./vcpkg.exe install openssl-windows:x64-windows
run ./vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows-static
run ./vcpkg.exe integrate install
run set VCPKGRS_DYNAMIC=1 (or simply set it as your environment variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

`sudo apt install librust-openssl-sys-dev`

Answer (score 1):

I encounterd this issue today. I'm not sure how and which Cargo.toml to add the "features = vendored".
Finally, I set some enviroment variables of Openssl and it works.

```
OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/
OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

You can check the exact path of openssl by running the following command:
dpkg -L libssl-dev

Comment: For detail path of Openssl, you can refer to https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.32/openssl/#manual

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more information from source [openssl crate docs](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/#automatic)

```bash
# macOS (Homebrew)
$ brew install openssl@3

# macOS (MacPorts)
$ sudo port install openssl

# macOS (pkgsrc)
$ sudo pkgin install openssl

# Arch Linux
$ sudo pacman -S pkg-config openssl

# Debian and Ubuntu
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev

# Fedora
$ sudo dnf install pkg-config perl-FindBin openssl-devel

# Alpine Linux
$ apk add pkgconfig openssl-dev

# openSUSE
$ sudo zypper in libopenssl-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

On **Fedora 39** in Jan 2024 - I had to run this:

```
sudo dnf install -y openssl openssl-libs openssl-devel pkg-config perl
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the *make* command is installed, it is not always pre-installed. You can run :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score -4):

Set variable openssl_dir to suitable PATH