# Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: docker, rust

the [rust-musl-builder](https://github.com/rust-cross/rust-musl-cross) stop maintain for years, then I tried to use [messense/rust-musl-cross](https://github.com/rust-cross/rust-musl-cross) to build the rust application to a static library, the build process shows error:

```
#9 13.77   run pkg_config fail: `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="/usr/local/musl/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/musl/lib/pkgconfig" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/musl/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/musl/lib/pkgconfig" PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/usr/local/musl/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "openssl"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
#9 13.77   error: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   --- stderr
#9 13.77   Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
#9 13.77   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'
#9 13.77   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
#9 13.77   No package 'openssl' found
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   --- stderr
#9 13.77   thread 'main' panicked at '
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
#9 13.77   proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
#9 13.77   trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
#9 13.77   compilation process.
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
#9 13.77   For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
#9 13.77   automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
#9 13.77   and include information about your system as well as this message.
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   $HOST = aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
#9 13.77   $TARGET = x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
#9 13.77   openssl-sys = 0.9.90
#9 13.77 
#9 13.77   ', /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-sys-0.9.90/build/find_normal.rs:190:5
#9 13.77   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
#9 13.77 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]: exit code: 101
```

this is my dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=messense/rust-musl-cross:x86_64-musl

# Our first FROM statement declares the build environment.
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS builder

# Add our source code.
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install pkg-config -y

# Build our application.
RUN cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

and this is the cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "alt-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
```

the `main.rs` look like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello world!")
}
```

Am I missing something? what should I to do avoid this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to Cargo.toml solves the issue:

```ini
openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }
```

Reference. A comment at [Why rust is failing to build command for openssl-sys v0.9.60 even after local installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553557/why-rust-is-failing-to-build-command-for-openssl-sys-v0-9-60-even-after-local-in)

Comment: you are a true legend sir! Nothing has helped, except for this! Thank you